# Creating a Digital Download facility and track downloads

Tags: user-meta

I need to make available Documents for download and I need to track the document name/number of downloads for each user and list of downloaders for each download, is this possible with WordPress, if so any suggestions ?

Comment: Also too broad, ask each individual part as a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can simply do all these with this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-digital-downloads/

Answer (score -1):

try this plugin, I am use this too http://wordpress.org/plugins/download-manager/

Comment: A link-only Answer is a worst answer. :(